# Getting the inode number of an unopen file from path

Tags: c, inode

Is there a way I could get the inode number of a file which has not yet been opened. I would like to do this from inside a c function

Regards,
Lipika

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stat(2)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=2) (which takes a file path), and check the st_ino field. Do note that it's possible for someone to move or remove the file between the time you call `stat` and whenever you manage to do anything with the information.

Comment: I would need to have the file "opened" and I don't want to do that. I need to do a few processings with the inode number and if I get a positive result i proceed to open the file.

Comment: Are you confusing `stat(2)` with `fstat(2)`?

Comment: @Lipika Why do you say you would need to have the file opened? It isn't true.

Comment: @Jim Mistakes all mine. Works great. I have been thinking we have to first open the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the answer can be found in this question:

[How do I read a directory as a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659071/how-do-i-read-a-directory-as-a-file-in-unix)

You have to read the directory which contains the file entry.  That entry contains the inode number.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have very tight control over the permissions on every element of the path to the file, what you're trying to do is almost surely wrong. Between any two operations involving accessing a file by pathname, there is a race condition, i.e. the inode number you get is potentially incorrect even before the call (`stat` or `readdir`) that gives it to you returns. Why don't you want to open the file?