# Can I view a linux directory in binary mod?

Tags: linux

I've learned that linux directory is a file. So can I view it in binary mod like viewing other files with hexdump?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a directory as a file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659071/how-do-i-read-a-directory-as-a-file-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

You can dump raw portions of a drive using the **dd** command and that is about as low level as you can get. You can also use **debugfs** to do maintenance on the filesystem.